# How do I give eDirectory/Symfony 2.8 more time? Error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, symfony, arcasolutions-edirectory

I set `max_execution_time` to 120 seconds.

```
$ grep max_execution_time /etc/php5/php.ini
max_execution_time = 120
```

I'm still getting the error

```
Error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

After several reloads, it will work (presumably it is compiling Twig and LESS to cache), but often it fails, especially for new pages or after running `composer`.

I don't see anywhere that it is set (lower) via code:

```
$ grep -r max_execution_time *
vendor/symfony/symfony/appveyor.yml:    - echo max_execution_time=1200 >> php.ini-min
web/classes/phpmailer/class.smtp.php:            $max = ini_get('max_execution_time');
web/conf/phpini.inc.php:    ini_set("max_execution_time", "3600");
web/simplesaml/modules/statistics/config-templates/module_statistics.php:        * Set max running time for this script. This is also controlle by max_execution_time in php.ini
```

I also tried to add `opcache` to speed it up, but it doesn't seem faster.

```
$ grep opcache composer.json
        "ext-opcache": "*",

$ cat /etc/php5/conf.d/opcache.ini
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20131226/opcache.dll
; Sets how much memory to use
opcache.memory_consumption=128

;Sets how much memory should be used by OPcache for storing internal strings
;(e.g. classnames and the files they are contained in)
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8

; The maximum number of files OPcache will cache
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000

;How often (in seconds) to check file timestamps for changes to the shared
;memory storage allocation.
opcache.revalidate_freq=60

;If enabled, a fast shutdown sequence is used for the accelerated code
;The fast shutdown sequence doesn't free each allocated block, but lets
;the Zend Engine Memory Manager do the work.
opcache.fast_shutdown=1

;Enables the OPcache for the CLI version of PHP.
opcache.enable_cli=1

;If you use any library or code that uses code annotations you must enable save comments:
opcache.save_comments=1
```

Symfony 2.8, PHP 5.6.27

Comment: Your grep may be failing to locate a programmatic setting of that value. I would use `ini_get` in the script and verify that way, or alternately explicitly set it with `ini_set` later in the code execution. Maybe need to be 'warming' your cache? Should look to upgrade to newer version of PHP too.

Comment: @ficuscr eDirectory requires PHP < 7.0.

Comment: Well then I question the claim that it's "The World's Best Online Directory Software"... But that's not your question. Is this just an issue of cache warm up? Can you invoke that code CLI instead of over web? Did you understand the rest of my first comment?

Comment: Also, FWIW: https://github.com/rlerdorf/opcache-status Can at least quantify that.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", 120);
```

to `edirectory\web\app_dev.php` around line 23 before it does much of anything.

As mentioned in the comments above.